# Getting all pin id's of a specific user

Tags: python, pinterest

Hi folks so I want to pull all the pin id's of a specific user (not me). I feel I am frustratingly close but lack that crucial bit of knowledge to tie everything together. Here is what we have so far:

- through the [API explorer](https://developers.pinterest.com/tools/api-explorer/) under Users we see we can return a
  specific user's information, in particular "counts", but not a list
  of the pin id's (that i can subsequently query)
- through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29881656/pinterest-api-limit-the-number-of-pins-returned) i see i can pull the most recent 50 pins but thats not the full list i want. someone's tried to page to the next 50 on the board side [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25353988/pinterest-api-board-paging) without much success.
- [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31137197/getting-all-pins-of-a-specific-user-pinterest/31606045#31606045) asked a similar question to me with a pretty unsatisfying answer (yes, all is good once we have the pin id, the problem is getting the full list of pin id's!)

please help??

Comment: You're going to have to provide code.

Comment: hi Eugene, i'm not reporting a problem in my code, because this question is more about "how do i go about tackling this problem", which is why i have linked extensively to the half-solutions I have found so far.

Answer (score 1):

Using the developer API you can log a user in and request /me/pins/.

`https://api.pinterest.com/v1/me/pins/?fields=id`

It will also return paging information for the next set of pins.

`https://api.pinterest.com/v1/me/pins/?fields=id&cursor=<cursor>`

Comment: thanks for your reply Zack, i'm interested in the pins of another user (ie not me). So I wouldn't have the login info of that user (so the me/pins endpoint is out of the question) and I cant access that info through the API because there is no users/{userid}/pins endpoint. just wondering if theres another way to get at it? user pins are publicly available information anyway right?

Comment: The only way to do that is through the undocumented widget API. The url is `https://widgets.pinterest.com/v3/pidgets/users/<user>/pins/`. The problem is that undocumented APIs have a tendency to change randomly.